# Set color of touched Pixel to FrameLayout

Tags: android, bitmap, background-color

Im trying to get the color of the touched pixel and set this color as a backgroundcolor to a FrameLayout, but it doesnt work. why?

Here is my code:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            float xPos = event.getX();
            float yPos = event.getY();

            ImageView iview = (ImageView)v;
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)iview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            int color = bitmap.getPixel(Math.round(xPos), Math.round(yPos));

            myFrameLayout.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(color), 16));

            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in parsing the color.

Using the int color directly should do what you need.

```
    int color = bitmap.getPixel(Math.round(xPos), Math.round(yPos));
    myFrameLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

However, if you realy want to parse it and reconstruct, use the Color.argb(int, int, int, int) method to do so, where the int parameters are 0x00-0xFF values for transparency, red, green, blue components of the color.

```
    int color = bitmap.getPixel(Math.round(xPos), Math.round(yPos));
    myFrameLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(
         (color & (255 << 24)) >> 24, // take the top 8 bits
         (color & (255 << 16)) >> 16, // take the second 8 bits
         (color & (255 << 8 )) >> 8   // take the third 8 bits
          color & 255)         // take the last 8 bits
    );
```

Hope this helps.